# Using regex to extract substring

Tags: javascript, regex, substring

I am trying to make a parser for PGN-file moves. I would like to extract a substring from the total text-input starting from move 1.

This is an example piece of a PGN file:

[PGN-file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvX9Q.png)

I tried to extract the moves in a `substring` using `indexOf()` by a regex.

This is my attempt:

```js
function extractMoves(){
    const pgn = '[Date "2013.11.12"] 1.Nf3 d5 2.g3 g6'; // Sample PGN.
    const firstMove = /1\.([a-h]|[NBRQK])/; // First move regex.
    const moves = pgn.substring(pgn.indexOf(firstMove));
    return moves;
}
console.log(extractMoves());
```

This is the expected output:

1.Nf3 d5 2.g3 g6

Comment: Please provide a sample input data that we can copy. Not an image.

Comment: You are passing a regex to indexOf

Comment: @dorukerenaktas const pgn is the sample input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`indexOf` doesn't work with regex. Use `search` instead.

It gives the expected output now:

```
function extractMoves(){
    const pgn = '[Date "2013.11.12"] 1.Nf3 d5 2.g3 g6'
    const firstMove = /1\.([a-h]|[NBRQK])/;
    const moves = pgn.substring(pgn.search(firstMove));
    return moves;
}
console.log(extractMoves());
```